# Persist page change using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have page that shows 3 different icons and a username per row. The user (for example, username 1) can click on the icon and it toggles between two images. Here is the code on CodePen. https://codepen.io/centem/pen/NgKEmG
I know I could probably use a simple SharePoint list and simplify things but I'm also trying to learn how to do this in a way that is not SharePoint dependent. Thank you.

The way I set this up was using a SharePoint Web Page Viewer. How can I persist that icon toggle setting to a file so that anyone viewing the page can see what setting the user left the icon on.

If username 1 doesn't have ie installed he/she clicks to toggle the image to an x. Then someone else viewing that page can see the setting.

I was thinking of using a JSON file. Is that a good way to do this?

```js
$('ul.list-unstyled li img').on('click', function() {
  var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
  if (clicked === '1') {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'))
    $(this).data('clicked', '0')
  } else {
    $(this).data('src', $(this).attr('src'))
    $(this).attr('src', "https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png");
    $(this).data('clicked', '1')
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 25px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

li {
  margin: 4px;
  clear: both;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f0f0f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
    When image clicked change image to:
    https://www.centerpointe.com/v2/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/red-x.png
    -->

<ul class="list-unstyled">

  <li>Username 1<span class="pull-right">
    <img class="chrome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
    <img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li>

  <li>Username 2<span class="pull-right">
    <img class="chrome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
    <img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li>
  </li>

  <li>Username 3<span class="pull-right">
    <img class="chrome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
    <img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: If solely for learning and to avoid sharepoint could use a cloud storage like firebase which is easy to access and update. Otherwise doesn't make sense not to use the back end you already have

Comment: Thank you for response. How would go about using SharePoint to write the state of the page to persist reloads?